# Removing directory from URL while retaining current directory files

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, iis, url-rewriting

I'm currently creating a website which uses the format

> www.fakewebsite.com/projects/CompanyName/ProjectName/

to link to specific projects based on a company. The issue is I personally would prefer not to have "projects" visible to the end user. So I would like to turn the above URL into

> www.fakewebsite.com/CompanyName/ProjectName/

The problem I have is that files within the base directory of "www.fakewebsite.com" which are essential to the website. The CompanyName/ProjectName is generated via a php script which automatically populates and creates the directories.

I understand from a few searches of StackOverflow that I can do this with .htaccess, mod rewrite or PHP but I unsure which application would be the "proper" fix which would be maintainable.

I am running a Windows Server 2012 IIS, with PHP 5.3 installed.

Comment: mod rewrite is the way to go. To implement mod rewrite you'll need to edit the .htaccess file

Comment: Appreciate your reply. Could you provide an example (I don't expect working code or pastable snippets, I would like to learn) as to exactly how I would go about redirecting without making the original files within the base directory unreachable? All my current solutions either do not work or do not allow me to access the base directory.

Comment: Upon even further searching (suggested pages) I found a useful tool which allows you to test your mod rewrites without having to constantly update your .htaccess.

http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

My issue appears to be solved with the following code too.

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^projects/(.*)/(.*) /$1/$2 [L,R=301]L]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding these rules to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+projects/([^\?\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^projects/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /projects/$1 [L]
```

Comment: This worked better than my previous implementation, and is working functionally. I appreciate your help with my issue.